# How to get onmouseover and onmouseout settings to work as desired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**The Issue**

I have a shopping cart for an online store and to view the contents of the shopping bag you hover over a div in the navigation menu. I made a prototype where the `shoppingTab` div actually touched the `trolley` div in the navigation bar that made it appear upon hovering. This then allowed me to move my cursor from the `shoppingTab` div in the navigation bar to the `trolley` div without the shopping cart disappearing until `onmouseout` which was strangely set only to the `shoppingTab` in the navigation bar, not the `trolley` div itself but I liked this odd little quirk. Therefore I would like to replicate this behaviour on to my new site.

Don't worry: I know what you've read up to this point hasn't been enough information to go off, don't worry there is more detailed stuff sitting below above my current code. You'll get what I mean when you scroll further down :).

**PROTOTYPE CODE**

Here is the prototype on JSFiddle (and it doesn't work `onmouseover`???) https://jsfiddle.net/Please_Reply/k1k566wp/1/ so just in case here is the raw code which will work if you copy and paste it into a blank HTML file etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
}
.header{
    width:960px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#06F;
    float:left;
}
#trolley{
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:white;
    float:right;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:black;
    border:1px solid black;
    line-height:30px;
    font-family:"Calibri";
    cursor: pointer;
}
.shop{
    width:960px;
    height:700px;
    background-color:white;
    float:left;
    font-family:"Calibri Light";
    padding:20px;
}
#shoppingTab{
    display:none;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:1px;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:black;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding-left:10px;
    float:right;
}
html{
    background-color:#00F;
}
.product{
    height:200px;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-right:20px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.product:hover{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <span id="name"></span><div id="trolley" onmouseover="tabDisplay('block')" onmouseout="tabDisplay('none')"><center>Shopping Cart <span style='font-family:webdings'>&#164;</span> <span id="NOI" style="background-color:red; border-radius:360px; color:white; padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px">0</span></center>
            <div id="shoppingTab">You have selected <span id="NOI2">0</span> items. Your total is $<span id="totalPrice">0</span><br/><span id="itemsList"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shop" style="font-size:28px">Welcome, <span id="name2"></span>.<hr /><br/>Products<br/><hr />

    <div class="product" onclick="addToCart('sunglasses', 0, 70)">Pair of sunglasses ($70)<br /><br /><span onclick="change(1)">Click to add to cart</span></div>
    <div class="product" onclick="addToCart('shoes', 1, 180)">Pair of shoes ($180)<br /><br /><span onclick="change(3)">Click to add to cart</span></div>
    <div class="product" onclick="addToCart('belt', 2, 20)">A belt ($20)<br /><br /><span onclick="change(3)">Click to add to cart</span></div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
var customerName = "";
var numberOfItems = 0;
var total = 0;
var items = [];
var stat = []

for(var a = 1; a <= 3; a++){
    stat[a] = false;
}

function update(){
    document.getElementById("NOI").innerHTML = numberOfItems;
    document.getElementById("NOI2").innerHTML = numberOfItems;
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = total;
    document.getElementById("itemsList").innerHTML = items.join("<br />");
}
function tabDisplay(displayStatus){
    shoppingTab.style.display = displayStatus;
}

function addToCart(productName, productID, price){
    items[productID] = productName;
    total += price;
    numberOfItems++;
    update();
}

function removeFromCart(productName, productID, price){
    items.splice(productID, 1);
    total -= price;
    if(stat[productID]){
    numberOfItems--;
    }
    update();
}

function change(i){
    if(stat[i] == false){
        stat[i] = true;
    }else{
        stat[i] = false;
    }
}

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("customer");
    if (user != "") {
        customerName = getCookie("customer");
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = customerName;
        alert("Welcome again, " + user + ".");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "please set up an account";
       user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("customer", user, 30);
           document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = user;
       }
    }
}

function changeCookie(){
    var user = getCookie("customer");
    user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("customer", user, 30);
       }
       document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = user;
}
checkCookie();
</script>
```

**MY CURRENT CODE**

I have a JSFiddle of my current code (Which doesn't work so I copied the code below as well. I think it is because I have pure Javascript in there which it is trying to read as JQuery??? I don't know... anyway if you can't fix the JSFiddle just copy the code that actually works below the JSFiddle link)... https://jsfiddle.net/Please_Reply/9uwj2bed/2/

So basically, in the code below, I need the `shoppingCart` div to appear when you hover over the `shopcartbar` div (probably using `onmouseover`). But in terms of `onmouseout`, I would like to be able to hover onto the `shoppingCart` div without it disappearing. I would like the `onmouseout` to work on both the `shopcartbar` div and the `shoppingCart` div just like it somehow does in my prototype???

One other issue when I use `onmouseover` on the `shoppingCart` div is that when I hover over any of the `.smallProduct` divs inside of the `shoppingCart` div, they seem to trigger `onmouseout` which is not what I want either, they are part of the `shoppingCart` div.

```
<head>
<style>
body{ /* Applies to the <body> tag */
    margin:0px; /* Sets the margin on all sides to 0px */
}
.container{ /* The container class */
    width:100%; /* This sets the width */
    height:100%; /* This sets the height */
    background-color:white; /* Sets the background colour */
    font-family:"Myriad Pro"; /* Sets the font family */
}
.header{ /* The header class */
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white; /* The sets the colour of the font */
}
div{
    display: inline-block; /* Sets the display type */
    float:left; /* Sets the float position */
}
#one, #two, #three, #four{
    background-color:black;
    height:90px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25px;
}
#slider{
    background-color:blue;
    height:10px;
    width:100px;
    position: absolute; /* Sets the position to a specific type */
    left: 0; /* Sets the number of pixels from the left that this object is placed */
    bottom:0; /* Sets the number of pixels from the bottom that this object is placed */
}
.inside{
    margin-left:30px; /* Specifies the margin from the left side */
    margin-right:30px; /* Specifies the margin from the right side */
    padding-top:7px; /* Specifies the padding from the top side */
    pointer-events:none; /* Specifies the cursor events */
    margin-top:25px; /* Specifies the margin from the top side */
}
#shoppingTab{
    display:none;
    height:670px;
    width:400px;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-2px;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:black;
    border:1px solid #323232;
    padding:10px;
    float:right;
    z-index:50;
}
.smallProduct{
    height:50px;
    width:390px;
    float:left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:16px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.smallProduct:hover{
    border:2px solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> <!-- This is the container -->


<div class="header"> <!-- This is the header -->
        <div style="float:left"> <!-- This is the logo -->
            <img src="logo.png" height="120px"/>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; font-family:'Myriad Pro'; background-image:url(images/loginsignupbar.png); width:535.1px; height:30px">
            <div onmouseover="tabDisplay('block')" id="shopcartbar" style="float:right; font-size:24px; margin-top:-7px">
            <img src="images/shoppingCart.png" height="30px"/>&nbsp;Shopping Cart (<span id="numberOfItems">0</span>)&nbsp;
            </div>
            <div id="shoppingTab" onmouseout="tabDisplay('none')">
            Shopping Cart<br />
                <div class="smallProduct" style="margin-top:5px" id="thmbproduct0"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct1"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct2"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct3"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct4"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct5"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct6"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct7"></div>
                <div class="smallProduct" id="thmbproduct8"></div>
                Total: $<span id="totalPrice">00</span>.00
            </div>
            <span id="topnavbar" style="float:right; font-size:24px; margin-top:5.5px">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right; clear:right"> <!-- This is the navigation menu -->
            <div style="position:relative"> <!-- This is the container of the navigation menu -->
                <div id="slider"></div> <!-- This is the slider bar -->
                <a href="link.html"><div id="one" class="item"><div class="inside">Button 1</div></div></a> <!-- This is just one of the buttons -->
                <a href="link2.html"><div id="two" class="item"><div class="inside">Button 2</div></div></a>
                <a href="link3.html"><div id="three" class="item"><div class="inside">Button 3</div></div></a>
                <a href="link4.html"><div id="four" class="item"><div class="inside">Button 4</div></div></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function tabDisplay(displayStatus){
    shoppingTab.style.display = displayStatus;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").animate({
    "left": $('#three').position().left + "px",
    "width": $('#three').width() + "px"
  }, 0);

  $(".item").hover(function() {
    $("#slider").stop();
    $("#slider").animate({
      "left": $(this).position().left + "px",
      "width": $(this).width() + "px"
    }, 500);
  });

  $(".item").on("mouseout", function() {
    $("#slider").stop();
    $("#slider").animate({
      "left": $('#three').position().left + "px",
      "width": $('#three').width() + "px"
    }, 500);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian I have gained over 100 reputation since you helped me out last :) but I still need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this section:

```
function tabDisplay(displayStatus){
    shoppingTab.style.display = displayStatus;
}
```

With this:

```
$( "#shopcartbar, #shoppingTab" ).mouseenter(function() {
 $("#shoppingTab").show();
})
.mouseleave(function() {
  $("#shoppingTab").hide();
});
```

Comment: I mean I had to make a few more changes that weren't in your answer but without it I wouldn't have been able to solve it so thank you!!!